# Atom installer packages doesn't work it shows error messages

Tags: css, debugging, package

I can't install packages in atom the installer shows error I don't know why it happened

I tried to install packages.
But it shows error messages
No packages installed yet.
I try to debug the code which I wrote but it doesn't work because its package didn't installed yet.
I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.